# Create Static Slice from another Static Slice?

Tags: rust

I have two static slices that look something like this:

```
static ITEMS_1 : &'static [&str] = &[
    "abc",
    "def",
];

static ITEMS_2 : &'static [&str] = &[
    "abc",
    "def",
    "ghi"
];
```

The first two entries of `ITEMS_2` should match those of `ITEMS_1`.  So, I want to define `ITEMS_2` as `ITEMS_1` appended with another item (or more) to avoid duplication.  Is there any sensible way of doing this?

Comment: Could you go the reverse way - define `ITEMS_2` explicitly and `ITEMS_1` as a part of `ITEMS_2`?

Comment: I think this is impossible without const allocations.

Answer (score 1):

If you really only have 3 items, I wouldn't unpack the macro hammer.

While you can't do

```rust
static ITEMS_2 : &'static [&str] = &[
    "abc",
    "def",
    "ghi"
];

static ITEMS_1 : &'static [&str] = &ITEMS_2[0..1];
```

you can do

```rust
static ITEMS_2: &'static [&str] = &["abc", "def", "ghi"];

static ITEMS_1: &'static [&str] = match ITEMS_2.split_last() {
    None => &[],
    Some((_, i)) => i,
};
```

Alternatively, you could also reference the elements one by one

```rust
static ITEMS_1 : &'static [&str] = &[
    "abc",
    "def",
];

static ITEMS_2 : &'static [&str] = &[
    ITEMS_1[0],
    ITEMS_1[1],
    "ghi"
];
```

Comment: Yeah, so I figured this was an option but its not super pretty :(

Comment: @redjamjar I had a better idea and edited. Whether you want to call this sensible is a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by encapsulating the common part in a macro:

```
macro_rules! with_common_strings {
    ($id:ident [ $($item:expr),* ]) => {
        static $id: &'static [&str] = &[
            "abc",
            "def",
            $($item),*
        ];
    }
}

with_common_strings!(ITEMS_1 []);
with_common_strings!(ITEMS_2 [ "ghi" ]);

fn main() {
    println!("Items 1: {:?}", ITEMS_1);
    println!("Items 2: {:?}", ITEMS_2);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=2eb6b8e636faebb6816580c7352aeed1)

Or with a more complex but more generic macro that doesn't hardcode the common part of the arrays:

```
macro_rules! make_cumul_arrays {
    (@rec ($($accum:expr),*)) => {};
    (@rec ($($accum:expr),*) $id:ident [ $($item:expr),* ] $($tail:tt)*) => {
        static $id: &'static[&str] = &[
            $($accum),*,
            $($item),*
        ];
        make_cumul_arrays!{ @rec ($($accum),*, $($item),*) $($tail)* }
    };
    ($id:ident [ $($item:expr),* ] $($tail:tt)*) => {
        static $id: &'static[&str] = &[ $($item),* ];
        make_cumul_arrays!{ @rec ($($item),*) $($tail)* }
    };
}

make_cumul_arrays!{
    ITEMS_1 [ "abc", "def" ]
    ITEMS_2 [ "ghi" ]
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=c710078c15ad59b3b3a38396dc5684c0)

Comment: Whilst this seems clever, its overly complicated for what I want.  I think the answer is: you can't do this.  Potentially, a macro could be written for appending static arrays?

Comment: @redjamjar remember that a macro can only access what it receives in its parameters. So if you give it the name of a static array, it will only be able to access the name itself, not the contents. That being said, see edited answer for a more general macro that doesn't hardcode the common part of the arrays (and that should work with any number of arrays).